# Perl variable is changing without any writing to it

Tags: perl

I have following script:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use List::Compare;
use Set::IntSpan;
use List::Util qw/first/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/firstidx onlyidx/;
use Data::Dumper;

sub get_index_by_data {
    my ( $data, $arr ) = @_;
    return onlyidx { $_ eq $data } @$arr;
}

sub detect_busy_intervals {
  my %params = @_;

  $params{epoch_key} = 'epoch' if ( !defined $params{epoch_key} ) ;

  my @all_epochs = @ { $params{all_epochs} };
  my @free_epochs = map { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } } @{ $params{data} };
  my $lc = List::Compare->new( $params{all_epochs}, \@free_epochs );
  my @busy_epochs = $lc->get_Lonly;

  @all_epochs = sort { $a <=> $b } @all_epochs;
  @free_epochs = sort { $a <=> $b } @free_epochs;
  @busy_epochs = sort { $a <=> $b } @busy_epochs;

  my @busy_indexes_list = map { get_index_by_data( $_, \@all_epochs) } @busy_epochs;

  my $int_span = Set::IntSpan->new(join ",", @busy_indexes_list);
  my @spans = spans $int_span;

  my @res = ();

  for my $i ( @spans ) {
    my $busy_start_idx = $i->[0];
    my $busy_finish_idx = $i->[1];

    my $busy_start_time = $all_epochs[ $busy_start_idx ];
    my $busy_finish_time = $all_epochs[ $busy_finish_idx ];

    my $prev_free_time_idx = $busy_start_idx - 1;
    my $next_free_time_idx = $busy_finish_idx + 1;

    my $route = {};

    $route->{start} = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$prev_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
    $route->{finish} = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$next_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;

    $route->{start}{epoch} = $params{all_epochs}->[ $busy_start_idx ];
    $route->{finish}{epoch} = $params{all_epochs}->[ $busy_finish_idx ];

    push @res, $route;
  }

  return \@res;
}


my @checks_arr = ( 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 );

my $data = [
  { 'epoch' => 100, 'cron_data_id' => 1 },
  { 'epoch' => 500, 'cron_data_id' => 5 },
];

print "Data 1: ".Dumper $data;

my $res = [
  { 'start' => { 'epoch' => 200, 'cron_data_id' => 1 }, 'finish' => { 'epoch' => 400, 'cron_data_id' => 5 } },
];

my $a = detect_busy_intervals( data => $data, all_epochs => \@checks_arr );
print "Result: ".Dumper $a;
print "Data 2: ".Dumper $data;
```

After using variable `$data` in function `detect_busy_intervals` `$data` changed its value (in particular, `epoch` value is different). But no any writing to `$params{data}` inside `detect_busy_intervals` sub !

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I checked code via perlcritic, maybe I made some syntax misprint that lead to variable change, but no problems detected.

Comment: Please post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: `use strict` and you'll see.

Comment: @m0skit0 The code is already using strict.

Comment: `$route->{start}{epoch} = ...` overwrites your `epoch` values.

Comment: @melpomene I can't see it on the posted code, neither can the browser...

Comment: @m0skit0 strict is imported by `use Modern::Perl;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these lines:

```
$route->{start} = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$prev_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
$route->{finish} = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$next_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
```

You assign hashrefs from the `data` parameter into your `$route` structure. These are shallow copies, so they reference the same hashes as referenced by the `data` parameter. That means these lines:

```
$route->{start}{epoch} = $params{all_epochs}->[ $busy_start_idx ];
$route->{finish}{epoch} = $params{all_epochs}->[ $busy_finish_idx ];
```

modify the original hashes.

You can instead assign copies (at least, one level of copy) from the `data` parameter by dereferencing the hashref (`%{}`) then creating a new hash reference containing the resulting list (`{}`):

```
my $start = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$prev_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
my $finish = first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$next_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
$route->{start} = { %{ $start // {} } };
$route->{finish} = { %{ $finish // {} } };
```

The `// {}` ensures that even if your calls to `first` return undef (when it finds no match) that the dereference will simply result in an empty list.

If your data structure may have further nested references, a general solution would be a deep copy from modules such as [listed here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bencher::Scenario::CloneModules#BENCHMARKED-MODULES).

```
use Sereal::Dclone 'dclone';
$route->{start} = dclone first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$prev_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
$route->{finish} = dclone first { $_->{ $params{epoch_key} } == $all_epochs[$next_free_time_idx] } @{ $params{data} } ;
```